# How to sort the array by alphabetical in asc and desc order?

Tags: php, arrays

I have set of arrays which need to be sort array by ascending and descending order in php?

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [product_name] => Blips
            [product_url] => 
            [product_id] => 123
            [state] => GA

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [product_name] => Alpha               
            [product_id] => 586
            [state] => GA
            )
)
```

Comment: How can you sort by "ascending and descending" at the same time? Is this array being built from a SQL query? If so using `order by` is probably a better approach, but you're going to need to clarify your ordering requirements.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I sort arrays and data in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17364127/how-can-i-sort-arrays-and-data-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

You can use usort and strnatcmp to achieve that:

```
usort($myArray, function($a, $b) {
    return strnatcmp($a['product_name'], $b['product_name']);
});
```

If you want it sorted in descending order then you simply reverse the array after sorting it:

```
$myArray = array_reverse($myArray);
```